# Proving grounds endless mode (DPS)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I recently started playing WoW again and I was pretty sad when I saw that there are guilds that boost casuals who don't deserve it through Challenge modes so I asked a old raiding friend of mine if there was anything you could do to represent your PvE skill (all my titles and apparently also the CM gear is worthless now) and he told me that there is an achievement for Killing 30 waves in the Proving grounds which is a solo scenario.

So I started with this stuff and now I unlocked the Endless mode. However I didn't really have time to test it out and my friend also told me it took him around 6 trys to finish it (a pretty long time if you take 1 min for every wave. He's a tank btw).

Since I didn't really have time to test the endless mode I wanted to know a few things:

- Are the trash spawns fix or are there just random adds spawning for 30 waves?
- Are there any new adds that didn't appear in Bronze/Silver/Gold?
- How hard is it compared to gold?
- Is there anything else I get from it besides the achievements?
- Can I use Raid Pots in there?

Comment: "Casuals who don't deserve it" ? You're seriously going to go with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Are the trash spawns fixed or are they just random adds spawning for 30 waves?**
The first 10 waves of endless are different to gold, but they are fixed. After that, each 10 waves repeats. Starting from the first wave, all of the enemies have a buff that increases their health by 1%. This buff stacks by 1% every wave, so although the wave order repeats, each iteration of that wave is 10% more difficult (e.g. wave 11 is the same enemies at the same time as wave 1, but is 10% more difficult).

**Are there any new adds that didn't appear in Bronze/Silver/Gold?**
There aren't any additional enemies in endless.

**How hard is it compared to gold?**
It's obviously harder and takes much longer (30 minutes approximately), so it will likely be a significant time sink whilst learning. You've already learnt all the different types of enemies in the previous challenges, so you know how to handle them. It is mostly about learning the 10 waves and optimizing your strategy for each wave (plan when to use cool-downs). After that, rinse and repeat, bearing in mind that the enemies will have more health each round.

**Is there anything else I get from it besides the achievements?**
Proving Yourself: Endless Damage (Wave 30) earns you the title, The Proven Assailant.
Your progress in endless is tracked and you can compete and compare yourself with other players. Other than that, no.

Endless Healer (Wave 30) and Endless Tank (Wave 30) also earn a title, The Proven Healer and The Proven Defender respectively.

**Can I use raid pots in there?**
Flasks and food can be used, but potions and other consumables can't. They do not suffer from the stat reduction, much like enchants, gems and profession bonuses.

A really great guide can be found [here](http://www.wowhead.com/news=219282/wowheads-guide-to-proving-grounds-strategies-bestiary-and-rewards). Good luck!